# how to get phone number,street view address on MKLocalSearch

Tags: ios, mklocalsearch

So I understand the code in the link below for the most part. http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2013/01/ios-6-1-simple-example-using-mklocalsearch/

However, how do I get the address for the mapItem? Seems like the other properties include: placemark, isCurrentLocation, name, phoneNumber, and url.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/MKMapItem_class.pdf

actually i am also getting the data like pizza, bar..etc but i want to phone number, street view address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MKLocalSearchResponse` item that is created by the `MKLocalSearch`completion handler contains an array `mapItems`. You should iterate over this array containing all `MKMapItem`objects.

```
foreach(MKMapItem *thisMapItem in mapItems) {
    NSLog("%@ - %@", thisMapItem.name, thisMapItem.phoneNumber);
}
```

You can read out every property described in your question from every `thisMapItem` object.